# FirebaseRemoteConfig getString is empty

Tags: java, android, firebase, gson, firebase-remote-config

hey guys I was having a problem with firebase remote config
basically the part I blurred out has a json array that looks like this:

```
 [
      {
        "owner": "1",
        "platform": "android"
      },
      {
        "owner": "2",
        "platform": "ios"
      }
 ]
```

and then in the "onCreate" method in java I used this code here:

```
mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
    .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(3600)
    .build();
mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings);
```

and when I try to get the value as a string with this code:

`String object = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getString("mobile_database");`

if I go in debug mode it shows that object = ""
it's just an empty string
is there anything that I am doing wrong?

I tried making research but I can't find anything useful?

Thanks in advance :)

PS (before someone marks it as duplicate these links did not help me :D

[Is there a way to create an audience of developer builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450256/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-audience-of-developer-builds)

[getString Outside of a Context or Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253328/getstring-outside-of-a-context-or-activity)

[FirebaseRemoteConfig getString returns empty but bytearray of remote config is not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52971807/firebaseremoteconfig-getstring-returns-empty-but-bytearray-of-remote-config-is-n))

Comment: Have you tried to set your minimumFetchIntervalInSecodns to 0 and restart your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the fetch method so the RemoteConfig is falling back to your local config if you have set one. See [how to fetch and activate values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-android#fetch-and-activate-values).

Comment: Hey! Thanks for that I overlooked that part. Now it does the request fine, but it only gets the first object in the json, do you have any idea why that could be? :)

Comment: So, `String object = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getString("mobile_database");
` this method returns only the first part of the json?

Comment: I thought it should get the whole string? Not just the first part?

Comment: Maybe you have set them up as conditional parameters in your Firebase Config console. Could you check it?

Comment: I just checked, and to create the value I only clicked on the "Add Parameter" button, entered the key and value, and clicked "add parameter" again. That's pretty weird isn't it

Comment: Ohh I good news! It gets the data correctly now! I think it updates every hour or so, I remember reading something about throttling, do you think that's the reason? How can I change this behaviour? Like I want to fetch the data as soon as the user opens the app, is that possible?

Comment: Strange behavior indeed. Maybe you are getting updates every hour or so because you have set `.setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(3600)`.